# How to get color and formatting data from command in not interactive shell

Tags: javascript, shell, colors, terminal, ls

I have terminal emulator in JavaScript that execute CGI scripts (via Ajax) and it would be nice to get colors and formatting information from the command, like `ls --color=auto`.

Is there a way to get data from non interactive shell (my CGI script) that display this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean but

```
ls --color=always
```

will output in colour even if the output doesn't go to a terminal

There's a `aha` tool to convert ANSI colour escape sequences to HTML (http://ziz.delphigl.com/tool_aha.php).

```
ls --color=always | aha
```

Comment: You're right, I was using `--color=auto` which dind't show them